# How can get a pop page result in navigator2

Tags: flutter

I am ready to use *Navigator2* instead of *Navigator1* in my flutter app.
There are two pages, Page1 and Page2. Page1 can push to Page2. When pop Page2 I want to pass a result to Page1. In *Navigator1* I can make it likes below:

```
Page1:

Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Page2()
        )
    ).then((result){
      //do something
    });
```

```
Page2:

Navigator.pop(context, result);
```

How can I do it using *Navigator2*.

Answer (score 0):

Save the Navigator.push future in popResult variable. The popResult value will be which you have passed from Navigator.pop(context, popResult) of Page 2;

```
    final popResult = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Page2()),
    );
```

Comment: Navigator2 uses RouterDelegate